# Frequency gap between neighbouring spectral lines

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics, frequency, spectroscopy

According to classical theory the atomic line spectra are discrete and their frequencies quantized.

Have the newer quantum theories changed anything since then, giving some other expressions for the frequency gap (or it's probability) between any two neighbouring lines considering the whole range (whatever that might be) of possible "colors".

What if we expand the question to include all sources of radiation that produce photons/electromagnetic waves. Would the frequency spectrum be discrete (like very narrow gaussian lines) or gapless?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is, so I'm not sure how to answer it.

"Classical" means without relativity or quantum mechanics?

Radiation was caused by accelerating charges. A charge can be accelerated any old way, producing a tremendous variety of radiation.

You got a sine wave of radiation by accelerating a charge back and forth, at sine-wave speeds, and the radiation was the most perpendicular to the acceleration. At angles it was decreased, and inline with the acceleration there was no radiation. The radiation was polarized in the direction of the acceleration.

If the charge was accelerated in a circle, you got circularly-polarized radiation in the direction of the axis of the circle, and linearly-polarized radiation perpendicular to that axis.

If the charge was accelerated in random directions, you got radiation perpendicular to whatever direction the charge happened to be accelerating at the moment, and fourier analysis could break that down into sine waves of various wavelengths. This light would on average be unpolarized.

The radiation from multiple charges was the sum of the radiations from each charge. I never understood why light from the sun or a star or an incandescent light bulb would be visible. Light the same wavelength from hundreds of thousands of charges ought to mostly cancel out. Imagine for the moment that the light is coherent. For each charge creating light with one polarization there will be a charge with the opposite polarization to mostly cancel it. And if it isn't coherent even worse, for each charge producing radiation with one phase there will be another charge producing radiation 180 degrees out of phase, cancelling it.

Maybe incandescent light does stimulated emission enough that lots of the charges are mutually coherent? And we get few enough different ones at any particular time that there's plenty of light that doesn't cancel?

So anyway, if (for example) free electrons get a continuous range of accelerations, then they should produce a continuous spectrum. Charges that are stuck in atoms accelerate in only a few special ways, so they are not continuous but make discrete identifiable spectra.

If you ask why electrons in atoms get those specific accelerations and no others, and why they are not continuously accelerated but somehow just float around without any acceleration most of the time, then you will wind up with quantum mechanics answers. Quantum mechanics is about atoms and why things stuck inside of atoms behave the way they do.